# How to add a feature to all the nodes in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

How to assign a number between 0-1 determining the sate of each of the neighbours. (That is in principle, each node has a number(state) associated to it! So that when I call a node; it has the information of its neighbours and their corresponding states! something like a Multi-dimmensional array in C!

So that the final information is something like ; node 5 has 4 neighbours which are 1,2,3,4 each with a state 0.1,0.4,0.6,0.8. I will further use these states in my calculations, so preferably an array containing this information will work.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(100,2)

for u in G.nodes():
    neighbors = nx.neighbors(G, u)
    print(neighbors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a dictionary, with the keys the neighbors of the nodes and the values the states of the neighbors, as attribute to your nodes.

See example below in a few lines:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(100,2)
neighbors={node:{neighbor:np.random.random() for neighbor in G.neighbors(node)} for node in G.nodes()}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, neighbors, 'neighbors')
```

You can then get the attribute by calling `G.nodes[0]['neighbors']` (here attribute of node `0`). And the  output will give:

```
{1: 0.7557385760337151, 2: 0.4739260575718104, 3: 0.9567801157103797, 6: 0.7574951042301828, 15: 0.30944298200257603, 20: 0.43632108378325585, 23: 0.36243300334095774, 26: 0.019615624900670037, 33: 0.555648986173134, 47: 0.6303121800990674, 49: 0.5832499539552732, 54: 0.4938474173850117, 80: 0.38306733444449415, 96: 0.19474203458699768}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! And how to convert the neighbors of a particular node to an array? such that I can further assign elements of this array with the attributes!

Comment: You can convert `G.neighbors(node)` to a list by using `list(G.neighbors(node))` (with `node` your node of interest). You can then convert this list to a numpy array if you want by using `np.array(list(G.neighbors(node)))`. From the dictionnary attribute I set up, you can get the neighbors of the node by calling `list(G.nodes[node]['neighbors'].keys())`

Comment: How to plot a histogram of the directory which you have created? i.e attributes (y-axis) vs nodes (x-axis) ; `{1: 0.7557385760337151, 2: 0.4739260575718104, 3: 0.9567801157103797, 6: 0.7574951042301828, 15: 0.30944298200257603, 20: 0.43632108378325585, 23: 0.36243300334095774, 26: 0.019615624900670037, 33: 0.555648986173134, 47: 0.6303121800990674, 49: 0.5832499539552732, 54: 0.4938474173850117, 80: 0.38306733444449415, 96: 0.19474203458699768}`

Comment: You could use `plt.hist(G.nodes[node]['neighbors'].values())` to plot an histogram and `plt.scatter(G.nodes[node]['neighbors'].keys(),G.nodes[node]['neighbors'].values())`  for a scatter plot.